# How do I save machine learning model(Kmeans) in S3 from glue ETL job in written in pyspark?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, etl, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I tried model.save(sc, path) it gves me error : **TypeError: save() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given**. Here sc is the sparkcontext [sc = SparkContext()]
I tried without sc in the signature but got this error : **An error occurred while calling o159.save. java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DirectOutputCommitter not found**
I tried multiple approaches using boto3 pickle joblib, but I haven't succeeded in finding a solution that works. I am creating a KMeans clustering model. I need a glue job to fit and save the model in S3 and then another glue job to make predictions by loading the saved model.
I am doing this first time any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the line after SparkContext solved my problem.

sc = SparkContext()

**sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("mapred.output.committer.class", "org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DirectFileOutputCommitter")**